# How to remove a line of data from text files

Tags: c++, vector, text-files

Ok so i am trying to create a program that asks the user to input a student id (i.e "12345") and it will run through a set of text files and remove the student ID from all text files. First it checks the "studnet.txt" file to see if the student is there. IF so, then it will remove the student from that file. If the student is in that file, that means he is also in some or all of the other txt files becuase the other txt files are classes. (i.e - biology.txt, chemistry.txt). So in the students files it looks like this

```
Students//this word is not actually in the file
100156
100167
100188
100177
123456
etc....

and the classes files look like this

biology
100167 98// the 98 represents a students mark in the course
100134 77
100165 54
100896 66
123456 88
```

there are multiple classes so the second part of this code runs through each class and is supposed to remove it. I am able to remove the student form the students text file but i keep getting errors when removeing from the courses. It must remove the grade aswell and keep appropriate format. Also this code is part of a larger group of code which contains headers and other classes. Some variables may be missing. Normally, running the full code would bring up a menu and when the usuer selects this option, it will make a call to this function.

-----update----
this is the error i get when i try and run it

Debug Assertion Failed!

Program:
...1\Desktop\Networking_Registrar\Desktop\Networking_Registrar.exe
File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector
Line:932

Expression vector subscript out of range

For more information on how your program can cause assertion failure, see the visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)

```
void Student_Logger::reStudent (int removeStudent,vector<string> classlist){
    //int student2;
    bool checkinfile = true;
    //vector <int> rstudent;
    int variable;
    int count = 0;
    vector <int> myvector;
    ///fstream rStudentsfile;
    rStudentsfile.open("students.txt");
    while(rStudentsfile >> student2){

        rstudent.push_back(student2);
    }
    rStudentsfile.close();

    //ofstream file;
    file.open("students.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < rstudent.size(); i++){

        if (rstudent[i] == removeStudent)
        {
            rstudent.erase(rstudent.begin()+i);
            checkinfile = true;
            break;
            //cout << rstudent[i] << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            checkinfile = false;
        }
    }
    if (checkinfile == false)
    {
        cout << "Student ID enterd is not registerd in the university." << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < rstudent.size(); i++){

        file << rstudent[i] << endl;
    }
    file.close();
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------this is the point where it checks all of the other files

    if (checkinfile == true)
    {
        string face;
        fstream openclass;
        for (int i = 0; i < classlist.size(); i++)
        {
            classes = classlist[i];
            openclass.open(classes.append(".txt",ios::app));

            while (!openclass.eof())
            {
                openclass >> variable >> face;
                myvector.push_back(variable);
                cout << variable << endl;

                if (variable == removeStudent)
                {
                    cout << "Hello" << endl;//lets me see if it chooses the correct line in the file

                    myvector.erase(myvector.begin()+count);

                }

                count++;
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < myvector[i]; i++)
            {
                openclass << myvector[i] << endl;

            }

            cout << endl;

            /*if (rstudent[i] == removeStudent)
            {
            rstudent.erase(rstudent.begin()+i);
            //cout << rstudent[i] << endl;
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < rstudent.size(); i++){

            openclass << rstudent[i] << endl;
            }*/


        openclass.close();
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: What errors do you get?  Update your question to include those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something more like this instead:

```
void Student_Logger::reStudent (int removeStudent, vector<string> &classlist)
{
    int student;
    vector<int> students;
    vector<string> lines;
    string line;
    bool found;

    ifstream ifile;
    ofstream ofile;

    ifile.open("students.txt");
    if (!ifile)
        return;

    found = false;
    while (getline(ifile, line))
    {
        istringstream iss(line);
        if (iss >> student)
        {
            if (student == removeStudent)
                found = true;
            else
                students.push_back(student);
        }
    }

    ifile.close();

    if (!found)
    {
        cout << "Student ID entered is not registered in the university." << endl;
        return;
    }

    /*
    TODO: to avoid corrupting your files, you should write new data to a separate
    temp file first, and then replace the original file with the temp file only if
    everything is successful.  If something goes wrong, you can simply delete the
    temp file and the original will not have been touched...
    */

    ofile.open("students.txt");
    if (!ofile)
        return;

    for(vector<int>::iterator i = students.begin(); i != students.end(); ++i)
    {
        ofile << *i << endl;
    }

    ofile.close();

    for (vector<string>:::iterator i = classlist.begin(); i != classlist.end(); ++i)
    {
        ifile.open(*i + ".txt");
        if (!ifile)
            continue;

        found = false;
        while (getline(ifile, line))
        {
            istringstream iss(line);
            if (iss >> student)
            {
                if (student == removeStudent)
                {
                    found = true;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            lines.push_back(line);
        }

        ifile.close();

        if (!found)
            continue;

        ofile.open(*i + ".txt");
        if (!ofile)
            continue;

        for(vector<string>::iterator j = lines.begin(); j != lines.end(); ++j)
        {
            ofile << *j << endl;
        }

        ofile.close();
    }
}
```